# ms-access How to subtract from column A first, and when column A=0, subtract from column A2(Substitute), and so on

Tags: ms-access

I have an inventory table and a query that subtracts my daily usage from it. I want my query to subtract first from the main color "true blue", and when that runs out, to then subtract from substitute color "Royal blue", and if that is also out, then subtract from "navy blue".  I also have stock in a few red colors and "True Red" is the main color, and if that runs out, I would want it to subtract from "cherry red" instead, and if that's also out, then subtract from "dark red".

```
InventoryCups (Table)

Description   QtyCurrent
True Blue     20
Royal Blue    15 
Navy Blue     5
True Red      10
Cherry Red    15 
Dark Red      5

PrintList (Table)

ToPrint       PrintQty
True Blue     22
True Red      28
```

I have an update query which deducts the quantities from my InventoryCups table when I go to print:

```
[InventoryCups].[QtyCurrent]-[PrintList].[PrintQty]
```

I want the output to be:

```
InventoryCups (Table)

Description   QtyCurrent
True Blue     0
Royal Blue    13 
Navy Blue     5
True Red      0
Cherry Red    0 
Dark Red      2
```

If it helps, I can also change my table so each main color and its substitutions are in columns instead. (Note: if I do that I won't actually need to know what the substitute color names are):

```
               ColorOriginal    ColorSubstitute1   ColorSubstitute2
 True Blue     20                15                 5               
 True Red      10                15                 5
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data and desired output. I doubt a query alone can accomplish.

Comment: Also review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: I revised the question and also reviewed your link; I'm not familiar with vba but it seems my question is a bit different. Thanks so much!

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstand what you mean by 'subtract' from each category. Do you actually want to change the saved values in table? If you don't care about summarizing by substitutes, need a way to group InventoryCups data by the broad color categories ("red", "blue", etc). If this data is truly representative of your data, extracting those colors from Description and ToPrint fields could be done with string manipulation functions.

Comment: Do you actually want to change the saved values in table? Yes! I am lost as to how to achieve this with string functions, any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Then my advice is "don't". Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea, mostly because cannot validate the data. Aggregate data should be calculated based on transaction records. Regardless of approach, you will need VBA in order to automate either adjusting saved values or creating transaction records. The coding would not be simple. Your question lacks attempt to resolve - there is no code to analyze - and essentially asks for someone to create code for your specific circumstances; therefore question is not really appropriate for SO. Saving aggregate data is a fairly common topic.

Comment: You say you have an UPDATE query - why didn't you provide that SQL? All you show is an expression that could be from a textbox. If you already have an UPDATE query, what exactly are you asking for?